# Calibrating and then posing a camera at known position, calibrateCamera, solvePnP, and optimization constraints

Tags: python, opencv, optimization, camera-calibration

I have a stationary camera with known position in a 3D point cloud scene. I know the exact position of the camera center to within a couple inches because I can see its location in the point cloud. I need to estimate the intrinsics and remaining extrinsics (orientation) of the camera.

I do not see any documentation or functions from OpenCV where you can put constraints or camera position bounding boxes into the DLT/Levenberg-Marquardt optimizations that are used in solvePnP or calibrateCamera. Let me explain my current workflow, which is not yielding satisfactory results.

- Establish 2D-3D point correspondences between a frame (imagePoints) and the point cloud (objectPoints).
- With an initial guess for the camera matrix and distortion coefficients, use calibrateCamera with [k1,k2,p1=0,p2=0,k3] distortion model and flags=cv2.CALIB_USE_INTRINSIC_GUESS + cv2.CALIB_FIX_TANGENT_DIST + cv2.CALIB_FIX_PRINCIPAL_POINT + cv2.CALIB_FIX_ASPECT_RATIO. I am certain that f_x/f_y = 1.
- Optimization loop: Use solvePnP on the point correspondences and optimal camera intrinsics from calibrateCamera. Look at the norm of tvec for the camera. I know the goal distance to the camera from the world origin. If the current estimate for tvec has norm too far away from the goal distance, scale tvec to have the correct distance and feed it back into solvePnP as the new initial guess.

The algorithm fails to converge. solvePnP always wants to snap back to its first solve. I know that this solve is wrong because it is about two feet away from the known camera position. Also, the point reprojections don't look perfect. I am confident in my correspondences, I don't need to use RANSAC to filter out the outliers.

Ideally, I would like to include the camera intrinsics into this constrained optimization as well. However, you cannot put an initial camera pose rvec, tvec guess into calibrateCamera. And the calibrateCamera output rvecs and tvecs I guess are for markers, or chessboard corners?

I am using the distance constraint for my optimization since that is a scalar value immune to coordinate system. Unfortunately, it seems that tvec always pops out of solvePnP as the world origin in the camera's frame. I don't know that information a priori. I only know what the camera's origin should be in the world frame, which is a vector independent of camera orientation (not true for tvec).

Does anyone have any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Forget OpenCV, Find or implemet some solver and use it for your constrainted optimization.